# SpriteKit dynamic set to false but still being affected by collisions

Tags: swift, dynamic, collision, skphysicsbody

```
var hull = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(64, 32))

var light1:SKSpriteNode = newLight()
light1.position = CGPointMake(-28, 6)
hull.addChild(light1)

var light2:SKSpriteNode = newLight()
light2.position = CGPointMake(28, 6)
hull.addChild(light2)

hull.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hull.size)
hull.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
hull.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
hull.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
```

Using Xcode sprite kit the hull (after multiple hits starts to rotate and sometimes move to one side. Initially it is unaffected. I checked to see if dynamic was set to `false` in the debugger and it is always set to `false`.

Comment: Are you sure that what's moving the hull is the Physics Simulator?  Maybe it's moving by another part of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the hull's collision bitmask to zero:

```
hull.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0;
```

I had a similar issue in a space-shooter game once and that worked great for me.